# Making a full page WebM with blur

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a full page blurred WebM with text on top of it.
Right now, I have (it's in jade):

```
block content
.header
  .overlay
    video(autoplay="" loop="" muted="")
      source(src="/typing.webm")
      source(src="/typing.mp4")
      | Video not supported on your browser
  .jumbotron
    h1 Title
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="overlay">
    <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="">
      <source src="/typing.webm"/>
      <source src="/typing.mp4"/>Video not supported on your browser
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS of:

```
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.overlay {
   margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The video is 640x480, and it is not stretching across the screen, but staying in it's native resolution. Any ideas?

PS. I'm awful at CSS.

Comment: Please post the actual rendered HTML instead of a pre-processed one—not all users are familiar with all pre-processed languages. That also ties in with the recommendation that one creates a MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the video to fit snugly in your entire viewport, you will need to add width and height styles to the video element itself.

**Live Demo:**

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.overlay {
   margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay > video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="overlay">
    <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="">
      <source src="/typing.webm"/>
      <source src="/typing.mp4"/>Video not supported on your browser
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this css should make your video responsive.

```
video 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```